# How to set app version on Firebase for web

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Using firebase on a website, is there a way to set the app version on user properties?  Every new release of the UI, we bump the package version and make it available to the app to use in logs.

I would like to set the app version on user properties, so that we can utilize the firebase app version features.

- Remote config greater then version
- Crashes on version
- user upgraded to latest version
- ...

I realize the the concept that this is web and users are on the latest version, but with service workers and spa this is just not the case.  We have auto prompting for users to update to latest version, but that does not mean someone is on the latest version...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not available. The app version is one of the [automatically collected user properties](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486?hl=en) by the SDK, which is only available for Android and iOS applications.

I'd suggest you reach out to Firebase support and file a feature request for this.

Comment: I get they are automatically collected, but doesnt that mean that if i got the user property key for app version, i could set it myself?  But I have not been able to determine the property name used... :(